# Google Maps Distance Matrix REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I did everything. This is my link

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=39.876678,32.749386&destinations=39.901374,32.760909|39.934519,32.85764&language=tr-TR&sensor=false&option=driving&units=metric
```

This works. But when I add my key, it gives REQUEST_DENIED error. (this is in a php code, I upload it to server, then I execute it. (I see the REQUEST_DENIED error with "echo".) So I guess I need to take a server api key) I can see the requested json properly, that's how I see REQUEST_DENIED

```
Key for server apps (with IP locking)
API key:    
AIzaSyAtLjmC2sNDBy8GY0ldL3QUMhXhqK*****
IPs:    
174.120.10.61 (THIS IS THE IP OF THE SERVER I'M UPLOADING MY CODES)
Activated on:   Apr 25, 2013 3:41 AM
Activated by:   *** – you
```

Can someone please tell me why am I still getting REQUEST_DENIED error?

Answer (score 2):

In my case was because I didn't enable this service for my project.

It is possible to enable here:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/distance-matrix-backend.googleapis.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use https instead of http.

http://. to https://.

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_DENIED — The service denied use of the Distance Matrix service by your web page.

Comment: but I don't execute it from a webpage, isn't it being called from a server? what should I do if you're right?

Answer (score 0):

Google Distance Matrix API has a limit of elements set to 2500. I highly doubt it that you would have gone over this limit, as you would have to have calculated the maximum 10 x 10 matrix 25 times over. I am from South Africa, and it refused to work for any local addresses until I changed the transport mode to driving (from walking, I mean seriously, we have cars). Maybe that'll help

Comment: I'm in Turkey, it works fine without the key, it shows distance, duration etc. it only gives error when I gave the key

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Distance Matrix web service does not use a key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#RequestParameters

Answer (score 0):

This is late but anyone might be facing the same problem now.

Here is a checklist.

**Use HTTPS**
Make sure you are making the request over https instead of http.

**API Key**
Make sure the application has access to the key storage and the APIs needed have been enabled on the Google Developer Console

**Check Request Parameters**
Make sure all request parameters are correctly typed.